# ROW_NUMBER() with 2 columns and specific case

Tags: sql, postgresql, row-number

I have table:

```
id doc_id loc_id price 
1  null   13     100
2  12     13     40   
3  12     null   300
4  null   null   150
```

I have to select from table the lowest price, but in that order:

1. If there is doc_id and loc_id equals to parameters then select this price (in our example it would be 40)
2. If there isn't check if there is row with only equal doc_id, if yes then take price
3. if there isn't check fi there is row with only equal loc_id, if yes then take price
4. If there are all nulls take price with nulls

The tables are of course bigger (there are few inner joins), but that's how final table should look like. I got suggestion to use ROW_NUMBER() with partition over doc_id and loc_id, but i am not sure how to to this.

Comment: Could you show us your expect result?

Comment: I am not sure why you would need row_number() here. Do you want to sort your prices or take one based on parameter you mention?

Comment: @D-Shih i think now the amount of money is ok. Finally i will havy many doc_id and loc_id so i will have to sum to and get lowest money for each doc_id

Comment: @Aarlaneth i want to take one based on parameter

Comment: @Serg true, I edited

Comment: @SebastianHalik Is it possible you get same doc_id and loc_id in multiple rows? I.E. taking your provided sample is it possible you can get row 5|12|13|60? If yes what should be your output? Lower or higher price?

Comment: @Aarlaneth i don't understand your answer. Example contains ALL cases. Of course in database will be more rows with for exmaple same loc_id but with other doc_id and in other way -> same doc_id but other loc_id. We are interested in only same doc_id and loc_id. If there arent these take with all nulls.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure where parameters should come from. Using a cte to provide a parameters row

```
with params(p1,p2)
  as ( values (12,0) ) /*sample params*/
select  tbl.*
from tbl, params
where doc_id = p1 and (loc_id = p2 or loc_id is null) 
   or loc_id = p2 and (doc_id = p1 or doc_id is null) 
   or doc_id is null and loc_id is null
order by case doc_id when p1 then 2 else 0 end + case loc_id when p2 then 1 else 0 end DESC, price ASC
limit 1
```

The ORDER BY clause first prioritizes the results according to the rules.

[db-fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/i_YZW8Wl)

Comment: Can You explain me how that "order by" with these cases works? Why 2 and 1?
Ok if i have doc_id and loc_id it would return -> order by case 2, 1. What does it mean?

Comment: The `case doc_id when p1 then 2 else 0 end + case loc_id when p2 then 1 else 0 end` expression is  3 (highest priority) when both columns match parameters, 2 when only doc_id matches, 1 when only loc_id matches and 0 if no matches at all. The last  one only can occur when both doc_id and loc_id are nulls according to WHERE clause.

Comment: Thank you for explanatio. Can u make this sql to case statement? In my app i have 

Select where i have all doc_id and loc_id selected from few tables. I wanted to count the price (with explainted previously conditions) in case statement.

Comment: CASE is not a statement, it's an expression. Under circumstances  a SELECT statement can be part of the CASE provided it returns a single value, which is not the case with the above query.  I guess you'd better ask another question providing sample data and the desired result.